# Redirecting not working properly in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

### What I want:

I have a private route (/dashboard) which can be only accessible when a user is logged in. So the condition I have is that load Dashboard only when the user is Authenticated and Loading is false (Completed). If the user is Not authenticated, redirect him to the login page.

### Problem

My code is working fine if I click on the Dashboard Link from the navbar. It redirects me to Dashboard if I am logged in but the problem comes when I try to manually go to dashboard by directly typing localhost:3000/dashboard.
Even if I refresh the dashboard it redirects me to login page.

### Reason

So the reason for this problem is that the two states (authentication and loading) are in Redux, so if I directly access the dashboard, redux takes some time to login the user and change the states due to which I go back to Home page even if I am logged in.

[image]

It takes some time because I have a token in local storage and which is checked by sending post request to backend to confirm if the token is valid, on Valid token, I get the user to redux state.

### Code

in **App.js**

```
<Switch>
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={
</Switch>
```

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
const PrivateRoute = props => {
  let route = <Route {...props} component={props.component} />;

  if (!props.isLoading && !props.isAuthenticated) {
    route = <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }
  return <React.Fragment>{route}</React.Fragment>;
}
```

You can see that the condition is checked instantly in Private Route due to which user is redirected to home page if he manually goes to /dashboard.

How can I solve this issue?

**PROBLEM SOLVED:** 
I have a little typo due to which isLoading was undefined always. By fixing that, it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

You solve the issue by making your webserver redirect to the landing page of your React SPA. It can be `/login/` but often it's `/`. At this point of time the page gets reloaded, the React application starts executing afresh, the React code determines (checking if there is a cookie and not looking at the Redux store that just got recreated) that the user is not logged in and redirects internally from '/' to `/login/'.

The webserver will not become aware of this internal redirect, it's internal to the SPA. But if the user types in a URL at the navigation bar and hits Enter (which I understand is the issue), then the webserver will know.

If you use webpack-dev-server then the kind of redirection needed by SPA can be achieved by setting [historyApiFallback](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback) to `true` and specifying the redirection URL.